# Long URL isn't fully blue when embedded inside SMS text message

Tags: ios, objective-c

In our app, we use MFMailComposeViewController in order to generate and send an invitation message, containing some text and a deep link. Sometimes, when there is a network communication problem, the deep link can't be shortened. When this happens, after the recipient gets the invitation message, the link is broken:
[image: SMS with a broken link]

I have no idea why it happens. Is there any way to fix this? By the way, if the recipient uses an Android device, the link is displayed correctly.

Comment: bnc.lt is a short url. you should use a custom uri-shortener to encode this massive uri into something smaller. because you're the generator of the data string, you have all info required to make this a reasonable uri. There are custom implementations of bit.ly you should use for this task.

Comment: Thank you. As I said, this only happens when connection to the bnc.Lt links server is not successful. In a normal situation, the link IS shortened.

Comment: ahh, just read that now. You should have a redundancy url shortener if this is a big issue. The reason _why_ it's happening is because iOS (and other url parsers) will just give up if the url data contains a large base64 encoded part. (although i've no actual source for that, it has just happened in my experience)